# How to get as a list the content of a csv?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a file (in this example it is "test.csv"). I want to get all the fields of this csv and make a list containing all of them. For example I can do:

```
import csv
def read_csv():
    dr = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
    result = []
    for r in dr:
        for n in r.values():
            result+=n
    return result
```

However it seems highly inefficient if the csv gets big.

I tried this:

```
import csv
def read_csv():
    dr = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
    return [n for row in dr for n in row.values()]
```

But it returns a list of lists, each containing the contents of one line, and not one big list with the content of every line.

What is the best solution for that?

Exemple of csv file (note the blank first line):

```
w1, w2, w3
w4, w5
```

Comment: Do you have an example for the csv file, and the list you'd like to get?

Comment: I don't see why the second approach should return a list of lists. `n` represents an item from each of the nested rows.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: I don't either, but it does. I tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're only using the dictionaries' values, you could replace [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) with [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and use a list comprehension:

```
def read_csv():
    with open('test.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return [col for row in reader for col in row]
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I will let some time before accepting it though.

Answer (score 0):

This will yield row by row of the CSV as a list:

```
import csv


def read_csv():
    file = open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        yield row
    file.close()
```

If you want a list with all CSV fields you can do:

#### Python version >= 3.3

```
import csv


def read_csv():
    file = open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        yield from row
    file.close()
```

#### Python version < 3.3

```
import csv


def read_csv():
    file = open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        for value in row:
            yield value
    file.close()
```

---

This return a generator, if you need the result to be a list you can do:

```
list(read_csv())
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a single list with all the data (i.e. not a list of lists), use `extend()` to add new elements to an existing list:

```
import csv

def read_csv():
    data = []
    with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
        for row in csv.reader(f_input):
            data.extend(row)

    return data
```

If your csv file contained:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

The `data` returned would be:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```